# C# Change XML value using Xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, visual-studio-2017

can anyone help me? I am kind of new to C# but getting there. 
I have been set a task to retrieve data from an XML file, change the data, and save it in another location using Xpath.

I think I have the code 'kind of' correct but I am struggling with the syntax with the path to the specific element. I have included a sample of the XML file which has been simplified but the layout of the elements is the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data SomeData which linked to a wepage.>
    <DeviceId>Sometext</DeviceId>
    <Inputs>
        <a:ImageInput>
            <a:Cal>
                <a:Volt1></Volt1>
                <a:Volt2></Volt2>
            </a:Cal>
            <a:Name>Name1</a:Name>
        </a:ImageInput>
        <a:ImageInput>
            <a:Cal>
                <a:Volt1></Volt1>
                <a:Volt2></Volt2>
            </a:Cal>
            <a:Name>Name2</a:Name>  <!-- Need to change this element -->
        </a:ImageInput>
    </Inputs>
</Data>
```

As you can see I need to change the a:Name element but within the second a:ImageInput element. I have looked for answers but I have only found examples where Xpath has changed part of a root element.

Here is my code which is used within the Main() method.

```
public static void ChangeFileXPath()//Changes the value of the node using Xpath
    {
        XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();
        xmld.Load(@"C:\ProgramData\Oxford Instruments NanoAnalysis\Calibration\mics_simulator.xml");

        XmlElement name2 = (XmlElement)xmld.SelectSingleNode("/MicsModule/Inputs/a:ImageInput[@a:Name='BSE']");
        if (name2 != null)
        {
            name2.SetAttribute("a:Name", "{{16}}");
        }

        string AmmendedFile = @"C:\ProgramData\Oxford Instruments NanoAnalysis\XXXX NewXMLReader\Xpath_Mics_Sim.xml";
        xmld.Save(AmmendedFile);
    }
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you for looking.

Comment: PS..Iam nee to StackOverflow to so sorry if this question looks rubbish. Iam a newb!!

Comment: Please edit the question to remove the image of code and replace with the text (formatted as code).

Comment: That xml seems to be missing a namespace definition for the `a` prefix. Please provide a valid XML. Are you bound to XmlDocument or could you also use XDocument instead? That would make your life easier.

Comment: @rene I am bound to XmlDocument, I cannot provide the original xml document as it has a lot of company material in there and I do not want the web to see it. The xml pic that I have provided is the exact same layout but I have left out some company info between the tags. What namespace definition is the xml missing? I am not sure.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what error?

Comment: @rene a colon is a valid name character in XML, it was then used as a namespace tag separator when namespaces were added. How well contemporary parses handle names containing colons without namespace declarations could be an issue, but namespaces continue to be an optional extension to the base XML specification.

Comment: @Richard ah, I didn't know that, let me verify if I can do without it. Hmm, it looks like the .Net XML parser doesn't like it. It wants `a` to be declared as a prefix.

Comment: @rene "doesn't like it": this does not surprise me.

Comment: Please add the sample XML *as text* to the question as well. I would try and solve this, but transcribing the XML from an image is too much effort.

Comment: @Richard it needed some juggling to make it work both for reading into the XmlDocument and make it work for the Xpath but my answer seem to produce the correct results without having the need for the namespace declarations in the XML file.

Comment: @Richard Sorry Richard i have been away from my desk in a meeting.I will try and include the xml sample but when I tried including it last time. It would not load for some reason. I will give your answer a go and let you know what happens.

Comment: `<Data>SomeData>` is **not** valid XML, `<a:/Cal>` isn't either.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Sorry about that, I have now changed the xml example. I didnot want to show the original xml as it holds some company information and do not want to spread it over the web. The xml example above is copy to show what element I need to change.This is my very first post on here so I knew I would make mistakes. Sorry

Comment: @D.Bodd85 that `SomeData which linked to a wepage` might be your namespace definition for `a`.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Oh yeah!! How did I miss that one. I will change the path now and see what happens....(few minutes later).....it works, you were right. Your a life saver. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: @Richard problem is solved, Thank you for your help. So pleased you guys are out there.

Comment: @rene Thank you for all your help. The issue is now solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> /Data/Inputs/a:ImageInput[@a:Name='Name2']
> ```

That is looking for `a:ImageInput` elements with an *attribute* `a:Name` with the specific value.

But the XML has an *element* `a:Name`.

Either treat as an element, with XPath

```
/Data/Inputs/a:ImageInput/a:Name[text()='Name2']
```

and then set the value of the found element in code. Or switch the XML to use an attribute.

**Update** Having looked at the XML

First: the XML is not valid. Eg. `<a:Volt2></Volt2>`: the closing name needs to match the opening.

Second: while technically XML can be used without namespaces (they are an optional extension to the original standard), the XML support in .NET treats "a:" as needing a namespace declaration (this applies to `XmlReader` which is the underlying parser for all the different XML APIs: `XmlDocument`, `XPathDocument`, and `XDocument`).

So you'll need to add an XML Namespace declaration to the document (and correct the mismatched closing elements noted above):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Data xmlns:a='this should be a uri'>
    <DeviceId>Sometext</DeviceId>
    <Inputs>
        <a:ImageInput>
            <a:Cal>
                <a:Volt1></a:Volt1>
                <a:Volt2></a:Volt2>
            </a:Cal>
            <a:Name>Name1</a:Name>
        </a:ImageInput>
        <a:ImageInput>
            <a:Cal>
                <a:Volt1></a:Volt1>
                <a:Volt2></a:Volt2>
            </a:Cal>
            <a:Name>Name2</a:Name>  <!-- Need to change this element -->
        </a:ImageInput>
    </Inputs>
</Data>
```

Given this the XML will load, and can be manipulated. With corrections to the XPath as above plus matching the XML the following works:

using System;
using System.Xml;

```
class Program
{
    const string Content = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Data xmlns:a='whatever'>
    <DeviceId>Sometext</DeviceId>
    <Inputs>
        <a:ImageInput>
            <a:Cal>
                <a:Volt1></a:Volt1>
                <a:Volt2></a:Volt2>
            </a:Cal>
            <a:Name>Name1</a:Name>
        </a:ImageInput>
        <a:ImageInput>
            <a:Cal>
                <a:Volt1></a:Volt1>
                <a:Volt2></a:Volt2>
            </a:Cal>
            <a:Name>Name2</a:Name>  <!-- Need to change this element -->
        </a:ImageInput>
    </Inputs>
</Data>";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(Content);

        XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
        mgr.AddNamespace("a", "whatever");
        XmlElement name2 = (XmlElement)xml.SelectSingleNode("/Data/Inputs/a:ImageInput/a:Name[text()='Name2']", mgr);
        if (name2 != null)
        {
            name2.InnerText = "A new value";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(xml.InnerXml);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your example. This does make sense as you are completely correct. I have tried the code but an error has been given.. System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.'

Comment: @D.Bodd85 now updated with code that does modify the element.

Comment: Thank you so much Richard, I had to include a namespace as within the data element, there is a web link so I had to call that before everything else as all the other elements are apart of it. I used your example though and just added the extra parts of the path. Thank you very much.

Comment: would the approach be the same for 100mb xml file? i need to alter node values and those nodes are identified by an xpath expression

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' That's a new question, but anything is going to be slow on a 100MB xml file unless you can avoid parsing the whole thing (ignoring the milli-bits as a typo).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the SelectSingleNode with that XPath you'll have to include a namespace by providing a Namespacemanager. And you'll need to have a valid XML file which I reconstructed here given the bits in the screenshot and your XPath

Creating an MCVE this code changes the node with a text value of `BSE` with `{{16}}`. Notice that I assume here that your XML doesn't have the namespaces and prefixes. Instead I provide them by means of an XmlNamespaceManager

```
// text xml
var xml=@"<Data >
    <Inputs>
    <a:ImageInput>
        <a:Name>BSE</a:Name>
    </a:ImageInput>
    </Inputs>
     </Data>";

    XmlDocument xmld = new XmlDocument();

    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr; // this will hold our namespaces with their prefixes
    xmld.Load(GetReader(xml, out nsmgr)); // xml can also be your file

    // we are going to find a text node, hence cast to XmlText
    var name2 = (XmlText)xmld.SelectSingleNode(
        "/Data/Inputs/a:ImageInput/a:Name[.='BSE']/text()", 
        nsmgr); // here is the namespace manager so it knows what a is
    if (name2 != null)
    {
        //name2.SetAttribute("a:Name", "{{16}}");
        name2.Value = "{{16}}";
    }

    string AmmendedFile = @"C:\ProgramData\Oxford Instruments NanoAnalysis\XXXX NewXMLReader\Xpath_Mics_Sim.xml";
    xmld.Save(AmmendedFile);
}

// Creates a reader and outputs a namespacemanager that fits for the missing namespace prefixes
XmlReader GetReader(string xml, out XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr)
{
    // code example taken from
    // https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/runeetv/2009/02/12/undeclared-namespace-in-xml-eg-xsi-is-an-undeclared-namespace/
    // from author runeetv and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/runeetv/author/runeetvashisht/

    NameTable nt = new NameTable();
    // add missing namespace prefixes
    nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "urn:why-was-this-left-out?");

    XmlParserContext context = new XmlParserContext(null, nsmgr, null, XmlSpace.None);
    XmlReaderSettings xset = new XmlReaderSettings();
    xset.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

    // return XmlReader.Create(xml, xset, context); // use this if you want xml to be a filepath
    return XmlReader.Create(new  StringReader(xml), xset, context);
}
```

Comment: Thank you rene, This will definitely help for the future as I have more of this sort of thing to do.