# Reading and writing to an XML file with a namespace without iterating through every element

Tags: c#, xml

Currently, I am writing to an XML. While I can indeed write to the XML file, I wish to only write inside the **"Fruit"** tag, and leave the info under "**NODE**" untouched.

Additionally, I wish to modify the "Code" tag that's within the country tag, not the one outside of it.

Here's the XML file contents (the URL is a bogus one that I had to sanitize):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Native xmlns="URL" version="2.0">
  <Header>
    <OwnerCode>Bob</OwnerCode>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <Fruit version="2.0">
      <Thing Action="INSERT">
        <Name></Name>
        <Color></Color>
        <Size></Size>
        <CountryCode TableName="SQL_Name">
        <Code></Code>
        </CountryCode>
        <Code></Code>
      </Thing>
    </Fruit>
  </Body>
  <NODE>
    <Name></Name>
    <Color></Color>
    <Size></Size>
  </NODE>
</Native>
```

Here's the current code:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(NewFilePath);
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants())
{
    switch (element.Name.LocalName)
    {
        case "Name":
            element.Value = "Apple";
            break;
        case "Color":
            element.Value = "Red";
            break;
        case "Size":
            element.Value = "Big";
            break;
    }
}

xdoc.Save(NewFilePath);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48658964/c-sharp-change-xml-value-using-xpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first specify the parent desired to only then get the descendants. The same logic you could apply to modify the `Code` tag:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(NewFilePath);
XNamespace xn = "URL";
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Descendants(xn+"Fruit").Descendants())
{
    switch (element.Name.LocalName)
    {
        case "Name":
            element.Value = "Apple";
            break;
        case "Color":
            element.Value = "Red";
            break;
        case "Size":
            element.Value = "Big";
            break;
    }
}

foreach(var el in xdoc.Descendants(xn+"Code").Where(x=>x.Parent.Name==xn+"CountryCode"))
{
    el.Value="Test";
}

xdoc.Save(NewFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping over elements, they can be addressed directly.

```
XNamespace ns = "URL";

XElement thing = doc.Element(ns + "Native").Element(ns + "Body").Element(ns + "Fruit").Element(ns +"Thing");
thing.Element(ns + "Name").Value = "Apple";
thing.Element(ns + "Color").Value = "Red";
thing.Element(ns + "Size").Value = "Big";
thing.Element(ns + "CountryCode").Element(ns + "Code").Value = "new-country-code";
```

Comment: Is that not simply hiding the iteration, rather than eliminating it? Mind you, the OP isn't clear on whether or not they're looking for iteration-less source code, or loop-less runtime.